# Angularjs filter a list with Union

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of players that belongs to a unique team. I will like to create a filter that triggered on a Button filter the list by 2 teams making a Union list i.e.

```
"Players": [
  {
    "Name": "Aron Baynes",
    "TeamName": "San Antonio Spurs",
    "TeamID": "4fd03d4e1c73bc0a74b81f24",
   },
  {
    "Name": "Michael Jordan",
    "TeamName": "Chicago Bulls",
    "TeamID": "4fd03d4e1c73bc0a74b81f18",
  },
  {
    "Name": "Tim Duncan",
    "TeamName": "Los Angeles Lakers",
    "TeamID": "4fd03d4e1c73bc0a74b81f11",
  },
  {
    "Name": "Stephen Jackson",
    "TeamName": "Miami Heat",
    "TeamID": "4fd03d4e1c73bc0a74b81f15",
  }]
```

I'm new on angular so I came up with 4 methods searching the web but neither of those worked the thing is in my HTML I have a button with a game lets say Chicago@Miami when you pressed that it should only filter the list to 2 players (Jordan and Jackson) using the Json above a united list like in a query get all the players that have the team Chicago or Miami. I know that a custom filter must be created but once is made it how can be called from the button and affect the ng-repeat? the button can provide info of the home Team and the Away Team that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create two scope items that can be used by your `ng-repeat | filter`.  When you click on the button via `ng-click` you can set these `scope` values.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="player in players | filter:filterFunction">{{player.Name}}</li>
</ul>
<button ng-click="setTeams('Chicago Bulls', 'Miami Heat')">Click</button>
<button ng-click="setTeams('', '')">Reset</button>
```

```
$scope.setTeams = function (homeTeam, awayTeam) {
    $scope.homeTeam = homeTeam;
    $scope.awayTeam = awayTeam;
};
$scope.filterFunction = function (item) {
    if ($scope.homeTeam && $scope.awayTeam) {
        if (item.TeamName == $scope.homeTeam || item.TeamName == $scope.awayTeam) {
            return item;
        }
    } else {
        return item;
    }
};
```